# can't install ubuntu 14.4 from a SD card

Tags: system

hi guys the reason why i use a SD card is that the 4 USB i have are down

my laptop is hp probook 4510s i have been trying to install ubuntu since yesterday my problem is ubuntu doesn't proceed to setup it stops after the purple screen with the logo then it goes to black screen says : 
(   6.871524 ACPI pcc probe failed ).
(   9.406018 sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] no caching mode page found ).
(   9.406052 sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache :write through).

busy box v1.21.1 (ubuntu1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built in shell (ash).
enter help for a list of built in comands

(initramfs)

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions from here ?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD

Does your system allow you to boot from SD ?